# How to compare events in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to give document onkeydown & onkeyup in same function

How to know which event that trigger the function ?

```
<script>

document.onkeydown = listener;
document.onkeyup = listener;

function listener(e) {

 if(e === "onkeydown"){
    console.log("onkeydown");
 }

 else if(e === "onkeyup "){
    console.log("onkeyup ");
 }

 else{
    console.log("unknown");
 }
}

</script>
```

Comment: `e.type` will give you the name of the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `e.type`

document.onkeydown = listener;
document.onkeyup = listener;

```
function listener(e) {

 if(e.type === "keydown"){
    console.log("keydown");
 }

 else if(e.type === "keyup "){
    console.log("keyup ");
 }

 else{
    console.log("unknown");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `e.type` but remove the `on` prefix.

```
function listener(e) {
   if(e.type.indexOf("key") !== 1)
      console.log("onkey" + (e.type == "keydown" ? "down" : "up")); 
   else { console.log("unknown"); }
}
```

Comment: Watch operator precedence.

Comment: I'm just not sure if e.type will still be without `on` prefix in IE. Don't have IE now to check.. Anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check [`e.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.type). `e` is an Event object, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

use this code:

```
<script>

document.onkeydown = listener;
document.onkeyup = listener;

function listener(e) {

 if(e.type === "keydown"){
    console.log("onkeydown");
 }

 else if(e.type === "keyup "){
    console.log("onkeyup ");
 }

 else{
    console.log("unknown");
 }
}

</script>
```

`e.type` return which event is triggered